# How do I get rid of the HWaddr that docker0 is using?

Tags: docker, ifconfig

I installed docker.io on CentOS several months ago and never used it for anything.  I have a license for another product that is tied to my MAC address, but the HWaddr that docker0 is using causes the license installation to fail.

I've uninstalled docker, but ifconfig still shows docker0 with the same HWaddr.  How do I get rid of the docker0 that ifconfig shows?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ran: `sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker` and
`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge lxc-docker`? You'll probably also want to `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`

Comment: No.  I hadn't done those things.  Is that required to remove the docker0 interface?

Comment: Sorry was assuming a debian distro - ignore :) Sounds like you got it sorted.

Comment: My bad for not mentioning which distro.  I'm on CentOS 6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a reboot to remove the docker0 interface after running `yum -y remove docker-io.x86_64`.